# How to loop through admin pages in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am at a loss which method to use. I am simply trying to loop through all the admin pages in the backend of WP. From there I'll check if there's matching meta criteria and then return the results to a custom backend page. But I've searched and can't seem to find any sort of method or other to query it. Appreciate any pointers!

Comment: Have you tried iterating through $GLOBALS['menu'] ?

Comment: That works! Care to post it as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from my comment,

Have you tried iterating through `$GLOBALS['menu']`